# How to Schedule a task in windows azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure

I have a simple Azure Worker role running that performs a task every day at 12 PM. Below is the code that accomplishes this.

```
public override void Run()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
              int time = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
              if (time == 12)
              {
                   DoSomethingElse();
              }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Add(ex, true);
    }            
}
```

Here `DoSomethingElse()` is a method to send an email at every day 12 PM, and also fires once and only once per day.

How can I implement a scheduler that fire when the time is 12PM and execute `DoSomethingElse()`.

My question is: Is this (above code) is the best method or use any 3rd party tool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure - how do I run a job that calls a function in the webservice every hour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548159/azure-how-do-i-run-a-job-that-calls-a-function-in-the-webservice-every-hour)

Comment: On a side-note, your code above will cause a tight loop, running the CPU constantly at 100% and may cause Azure to restart your worker role. You need to at the very least put a sleep statement in there. Or use a timer to wait. But, in any case, due to multi-instance you need to look for other answers to the scheduling like what Makogon is talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several other questions here that deal with this (and I've marked one above). Having said that, and at the risk of repeating what other answers already state:

In your case, a simple message on a Windows Azure Queue, time-delayed to not show up until noon, would work. This also helps deal with multi-instance scenarios: If you're running two instances of your role, you don't want the same scheduled task running twice, so you need a way to have only one of those instances execute this code. This is easily handled via queue message, or you could run scheduler code on a single instance by using something like a blob lease (which may only have one write-lock against it) as a mutex. This is covered in @smarx's blog post, [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-a-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure).

Comment: But i have a doubt that if i implement it via queue message same problem still exixt becase multiple instance will create multiple que message at same time..?

Comment: True, it's a startup issue. Consider a mutex via blob lock. @smarx covered this in his blog post [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-a-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure).

Comment: Azure now has a simple scheduler service that calls an endpoint based on a highly configurable schedule. The problem is that it doesn't work for long running processes. The timeout is 30s and is not configurable.

Comment: "This is easily handled via queue message" But how do you ensure only a single queue message gets added each day?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Quartz.Net http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/
using the blob lease mentioned ab ove is a great way to make sure only one of your instances is hosting tasks.

[Using Quartz.Net to Schedule Jobs in Windows Azure Worker Roles](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/using-quartz-net-to-schedule-jobs-in-windows-azure-worker-roles)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Scheduler specifically deals with task scheduling in the cloud.

I just came across this so I Haven't tried it.

http://getcloudscheduler.com/

**Update**: Forget cloud scheduler! I ran my daily schedule 600 times consecutively resulting on 600 email being sent to my clients. Don't use!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Azure Task Scheduler](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/).  Nice tutorial by Scott Gu [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/windows-azure-new-scheduler-service-read-access-geo-redundant-storage-and-monitoring-updates).

Specifically, I would look at the Storage Queue action type - just register for queue events in your Worker Role.

(Note that this service may cost money if you want to schedule tasks more frequently than every hour.)

Comment: I agree. This is the simpelest way. Just use a webhook to trigger the event. The Azure Task Scheduler is ridiculously expensive however for what it does.