# Using time specific timer in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, timer, scheduler

I have my worker role and I need to run a specific task exactly at 10 AM each day.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {                  
        while (true)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10)
            {
                //Do Specific timer Job();
            }
            //Do Normal Worker process();

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        }
    }
```

This runs the timer job multiple times since I get only the hour,
I cant just check it with a specific time say 10.00 since there is a chance that it might be skipped by the main worker process.

I need to know the ideal way to implement this.

I have seen this link and those mentioned in the answers,

[How to Schedule a task in windows azure worker role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897404/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-windows-azure-worker-role)

But I need a solution without using azure scheduler, or any third party tool :(
Anyway by which I can use timers to check with the specific time ?

Comment: Can you not use Quartz.Net library as mentioned in the link you provided? It is open source, extremely robust and highly configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use Azure WebJobs

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#Scheduler

And also, today's post from Scott Hanselman with variety of libraries including Quartz.Net from previous commentator.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Insert a simple queue message and set the visibility timeout of that message. So that the message will be visible only at that time and you can do the action.

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {                  
        while (true)
        {
            CloudQueueMessage queuemessage = queuestorage.GetMessage(queue name)
            if(queueMessage.exist && queueMessage insertion time < 10 am today)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 10)
                {
                    //Do Specific timer Job();
                    //Delete the queue message and insert new one for the task next day.
                }
            }

            //Do Normal Worker process();

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But creating another queue for this, involves additional pricing right ? I am looking for may be less simpler approach.