# How to create a schedule task on Azure

Tags: c#, azure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommend a C# Task Scheduling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507247/recommend-a-c-sharp-task-scheduling-library)
>   [Azure Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571439/azure-task-scheduler)

I will like to know is there a way I could create a scheduled task. Like lets say each day at 6 pm I will like to check the database for new entries and send an email notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "best practice" method shown in the BUILD 2012 Conference last week:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx

There are a few cloud service/IaaS videos that talk about this.

Comment: This won't necessarily work well in Windows Azure, as you typically want a scheduled task running only once. If you configure this on a per-machine basis, you'll have multiple schedulers running. You need to create a single-instance scheduler (typically using a blob lease to facilitate a mutex across instances).