# cloud scheduler

Tags: azure, scheduler, quartz.net, lokad-cqrs

Well of course we could use quartz.net, which comes with nice features like concurrency control and load balancing. However it seems a bit bloated to me.

1) Am I wrong about this ? 
2) If not how would you implement a cloud compliant scheduler (ie: either deployed on premise or within azure) ? Is [Lokad scheduling](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/7/20/lokad-cqrs-advanced-task-scheduling-with-calendars-in-the-cl.html) the best approach ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by cloud scheduler? or cloud compliant scheduler?

Comment: My main concern is to get a scheduler running on azure (so a cloud scheduler). However a cloud compliant scheduler would certainly be fine.

Comment: What kind of scheduler are you looking for? Do you need to schedule simple system tasks, or are you looking for a framework to develop a distributed application?

Comment: @tomconte : I'm looking for a framework, to schedule my own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers to this question ( [Recommend a C# Task Scheduling Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507247/recommend-a-c-task-scheduling-library) ) quartz.net running in a worker role instance is the way to go.