# Scheduled Events in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, notifications

My website needs to somehow do something every few minutes.

Essentially I get projects from another website. I then call one of my web pages and update.

Currently I'm making a console app for this but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507247/recommend-a-c-sharp-task-scheduling-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are super cool, open source tool exist for creating a scheduled jobs in .NET
It called [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).
I think currently is #1 tool for that tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Use windows task scheduler to run the console app your writing at the appropriate times.

Comment: This is the way I'm doing it, too. Could not imagine a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what needs to be done, there are a few options.

1. This can be achieved by a timer in a windows service.
2. Using the HttpCache expiration callback feature (not recommended, it is a hack).
3. Use a Sql job (assuming data is changing).
4. Building upon @Ph0en1x answer, there already is a Stackoverlow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/how-to-use-quartz-net-with-asp-net) on how to use Quartz.Net in ASP.Net