# Configure cron job that is executing every 15 minutes on Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire, ncron

I am using Hangfire and like the software very much! But one thing I am missing is how to add a recurring job that executes every few minutes (e.g. every 15 minutes). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use this (http://www.cronmaker.com/) to generate cron expressions. And then (as per the accepted answer) you can call RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Recurring"), cronText);

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Currently I am using this approach:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Recurring"), "*/15 * * * *");
```

And is working like a charm.

Reference to my question in Hangfire forums: http://discuss.hangfire.io/t/how-to-create-cron-job-that-is-executing-every-15-minutes/533

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Didn't know Hangfire accepted those cron expressions.

Comment: For 30 min  = "*/30 * * * *" ?

Comment: Yes, `*/30 * * * *` will be for `every 30 minutes`

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to stagger your tasks i.e. not have them all run at once at 00:00, 00:15, 00:30 using this method it will not work. I still havent found a way around that

Comment: Can you please help me with this question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422631/net-framework-to-manage-background-running-processess-on-seperate-machines

Comment: How can I specify “every 10 seconds”?

Answer (score 7):

We can also use  the following code line to schedule job for every 15 minutes.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Recurring"), Cron.MinuteInterval(15));
```

Comment: MinuteInterval will be removed in 2.0.0

Comment: how set the start time, for example, 8 am and schedule job for every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at Hangfire.Cron class I don't know if it's possible.

A workaround would be to create four different schedules i.e:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Transparent!"), 
    Cron.Hourly(0));

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Transparent!"), 
    Cron.Hourly(15));

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Transparent!"), 
    Cron.Hourly(30));

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => Console.WriteLine("Transparent!"), 
    Cron.Hourly(45));
```

Answer (score 2):

try the official tool for [CronExpression](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*):

```
https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*
```