# How to schedule a C# Windows Service to run a method daily?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, scheduling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

I am creating a C# Windows Service, but I didn't figure out the best way to make timer fire a method daily at a specific time specified in App.Config file (e.g. daily at 6:00AM, my method is executed).

How do you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This code should do it:

```
Trigger tg = new DailyTrigger();
ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks();
Task t = st.OpenTask("foo");
t.Triggers.Add(tg);
t.Save();
```

Comment: What namespace and/or assembly are those classes in?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Create a scheduled task. It's by far the easiest way. If you've got enough access to install a service you should have enough access to set up a scheduled task.