# How can I get my windows service to run at a specific interval?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I want to write a windows service. But it needs to run at specific times. For example, my service should email me every 5 minutes.

```
private Timer _timer;
private DateTime _lastRun = DateTime.Now;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _timer = new Timer(10 * 60 * 1000); // every 10 minutes
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    //...
}


private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // ignore the time, just compare the date
    if (_lastRun.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        // stop the timer while we are running the cleanup task
        _timer.Stop();
        //
        // do cleanup stuff
        //
        _lastRun = DateTime.Now;
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

I want my service to email me every 5 minutes.

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to be honest. It's really hard to provide anything helpful with no code. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

Comment: This question been asked, here is the link.
You use this System.Threading.Timer this is the key to success
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer

Comment: I want to mail me , ı edit my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I have seen another question which discusses [windows service vs scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390307/windows-service-vs-scheduled-task) also [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/10/24/10997.aspx). So you might want to have a look at that other than that here is 2 similar questions which might help:

- [How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)
- [How to schedule a C# Windows Service to run a method daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922444/how-to-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-run-a-method-daily)

here too are some great links:

- [C# Scheduler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2478/C-Scheduler)
- [Schedule Windows Service to run twice a week through C# code](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/157909/Schedule-Windows-Service-to-run-twice-a-week-throu.aspx#answer1)
- [How to schedule windows service in c#?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/268a194c-747d-40b6-8b9e-903e44e47686/)

Comment: And run at `7:00 a.m to 21:00 pm` interval each day ***Monday To Friday*** ? ***Not eastern-holidays***

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net) or search for "Windows Task Scheduling".

The first approach is programmatic and the later is configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a timer to your service who does what you want on the interval you configure?

Answer (score 1):

The article gives a walkthorugh how to creat windows Service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.80).aspx

And to run it at a certain time you can set schedule job

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something like [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) in your service. You can then use cron expressions to schedule "jobs" within your service.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good, but did you make a call to timer.start() in the first place during OnStart?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do an operation on a timer, then you have two choices

1. Create a Windows Service and implement some kind of scheduling. This can be complex, so be prepared to that you may spend a lot of time solving issues that have already been solved.
2. You could setup a scheduled task instead that calls your application.

It all depends how much control you really need.

Answer (score 0):

For the above said functionality, you can use the combination of console application with windows scheduler.

Schedule your exe to execute every 5 mins. Your exe will email you and stop. Is there anything specific you want to achieve through windows service?