# Running background tasks in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hai guys,

```
    I ve implemented the following code in the below link:
```

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Can i implement it for sending mails once in a day and i want to send mail at 6.00AM india time... Plz help me guys.....

Comment: What is the nature of tasks you are looking to run? If you are looking to run IO bound tasks then you may want to check out AsyncPages in ASP.NET:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find that particular bit of code a ghastly hack. Anyways you can send code via your c# code using the [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class (example code in link). Just put it in the appropriate CacheExpiration method with a timeout of 60*60*24.

I'd recommend looking at some of the answers in [How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily) for other ways of handling daily tasks.

As an aside, I can't speak for anyone else but I'm usually tempted to just skip over any question that ends in "Plz help me guys..."

Comment: Funny, I'm always tempted to skip over answers that end with "As an aside".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with the same concept as described in the blog , you can use the extension

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a4a4f042-ffd3-42f2-a689-290ec13011f8

Implement the abstract class AbstractScheduledTask eg

```
 public class EmailTestTask : AbstractScheduledTask
```

then write your code inside the Execute method . you can call the static class like this to run EmailTestTask's Execute method after 10 min

```
ScheduleUtilityFactory.AddScheduleTaskToBatch(new EmailTestTask(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), " RUN AFTER 10 MIN "));
```