# How to execute Windows service at a specified time daily

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to schedule windows service on daily basis at pre-defined time to run and then sleep till the next day, How can i do that?

Solution:

Added a timer to timeout every 30 minutes and then validate if the time of the day has reached, if yes then perform the desired function, make sure that, mark a flag once its done for the day.

Comment: This should have been a ServerFault question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't. You setup a scheduled task; services as (generally) for background running processes.

Comment: Ack. Although you might consider adding a timer if the service *also* should perform periodic tasks (checking for updates, cleaning up work folders or whatever) besides its main purpose.

Answer (score 5):

[How might I schedule a C# Windows service to perform a task daily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

Answer (score 0):

You can start or stop a service using a batch file.

Full details [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/235/create-batch-file-to-start-or-end-window-services/)

Then just add a scheduled task to start or stop the batch file