# How to schedule a C# code execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using ASP.Net and C#. I want to synchronise something on a particular time. I made a method for doing this and it's working. But my problem is how to call this method daily at a particular time.

Client doesn't trust any third party tool, so can't use it.

Windows service is not a good solution.

If I make a web service, how should I call it at a particular time on a daily basis?

For example, I want to run method everyday at 07.00 PM.

Comment: What you're talking about is a cron job. You could have a windows schedule request your page at a specified time.

Comment: @gideon, windows schedule request, how? Pls keep in mind, my application is using a sharing server, so we don't have RDP and enough rights to do more

Comment: Hm. Could you clarify what kind of third party tools your client doesn't trust?

Comment: Financial domain clients like AMEX doesn't trust on ANY third party tools :( They want to do every task within own environment only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At startup, add an item to the HttpRuntime.Cache with a fixed expiration.
When cache item expires, do your work, such as WebRequest or what have you.
Re-add the item to the cache with a fixed expiration.

```
private static CacheItemRemovedCallback OnCacheRemove = null;

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddTask("DoStuff", 60);
}

private void AddTask(string name, int seconds)
{
    OnCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, seconds, null,
        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, OnCacheRemove);
}

public void CacheItemRemoved(string k, object v, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{
    // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest
    // re-add our task so it recurs
    AddTask(k, Convert.ToInt32(v));
}
```

Comment: It won't affect performance, if I want to execute task after one day or more, I need to keep cache for one or more days, Isn't it?

Comment: If Depends on How much tasks you need to cache. obviously No of task should be limited.

Comment: @CoDeaDDict: For Example, I want to run method everyday at 07.00 PM. Could it feasible to do through this cache expiration?

Comment: Why not. it is simply a place where you can do anything, if resources are accessible.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. If you could tell me how? it would be appreciated.

Comment: call you method o this line // do stuff here if it matches our taskname, like WebRequest

Comment: @CoDeaDDict: For Example, I want to run method everyday at 07.00 PM, What time should be written in cache expiration, to call it daily on 07.00 PM?

Comment: calculate your time in seconds from current time to 07:00 PM and pass.

Comment: Hi Rab Nawaz/Pankaj, I have to do similar type task in my shared server where my application is host and perform some task everyday so i follows your given step,it does not work after few hours.Have you crack this situation especially pankaj how to achieve your requirement plz  let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows scheduled task to run the application (exe) or [create windows service and use timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily). Take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) it also can used.

Comment: Quartz.NET is open source, so we can't use that.

Comment: @PankajTiwari but you cant depend on HttpRuntime for daily job schedules also. It get cycled