# Creating a scheduler in C# to connect PublishThis API

Tags: c#, api, scheduler, global-asax

I want to create a scheduler which does following

- Setup a scheduler that loops every 5 minutes
- Inside of this scheduler, the following is done:

  - If there is a timestamp stored from a previous loop, use it
  - If scheduler is running for the first time, take the current time into a timestamp value
- Call the method [http://webapi.publishthis.com/rest/mixes/mixTemplates/?token=TOKEN:E4/TOrnj0kII13i7un7wnpTY7NSbBEPHNic8RAQKbkaB+siGaxk467A==](http://webapi.publishthis.com/rest/mixes/mixTemplates/?token=TOKEN%3aE4/TOrnj0kII13i7un7wnpTY7NSbBEPHNic8RAQKbkaB+siGaxk467A==)

Can you please help to achieve it?

Comment: Hopefully it's ok to post that token out here...

Comment: That is a sample URL with dummy token

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to make a console program, and just set it as a scheduled task that runs every 5 minutes.

If you  have to make it part of the web project, then there are other questions about doing that:

- [How to schedule a C# code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794534/how-to-schedule-a-c-sharp-code-execution)
- [Whats the best way to run a time consuming script in ASP.NET at regular intervals on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879065/whats-the-best-way-to-run-a-time-consuming-script-in-asp-net-at-regular-interval?lq=1)
- [Schedule task in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243353/schedule-task-in-asp-net?lq=1)

Comment: Can I achieve the functionality using global.asax?

Comment: Take a look at the [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) open source project. The project was designed specifically for scheduling web tasks and it includes async processing as well. The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/SageAnalytic/Revalee).