# How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to run some tasks in `Asp.net MVC`, after every 5 minutes. I've never worked on such functionality. So i googled it and got some options to implement this functionality. These are the options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243353/schedule-task-in-asp-net),  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794534/how-to-schedule-a-c-sharp-code-execution) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

I've looked over the above links. These all just confuse the person to choose best process to run background process.

I'm new on such functionality, that's why I'm here to discuss/ask the several ways available to implement it.

Comment: You can also use a hosted service for this. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) It's a fantastic framework for background jobs in ASP.NET.You can find [HangFie Tutorial Here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/highlight.html).

The best feature from Hangfire is its built in /hangfire dashboard that shows you all your scheduled, processing, succeeded and failed jobs. It's really a nice polished addition.

All these libraries are excellent, are open source, and Available as [Nuget Packages](https://www.nuget.org/).

[image]

**Some Other Options**

[QUARTZ.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

[FLUENTSCHEDULER](https://github.com/jgeurts/FluentScheduler)

[WEBBACKGROUNDER](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder)

Comment: I was confused in only two options and you have given me more.. thanks btw.

Comment: @CodeRider I would recommend hangfire please take a look it'll definitely help you

Comment: I've a question that if no one will hit site url for one week, would this job keep running in back-end or it needs to hit the url to start some event.

Comment: No that doesn't not matter if someone visit site or not this job'll start on webserver and keep running until your webserver(IIS) stopped. and maje it running always please read a good Doc [Here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html)

Comment: Phil Haack wrote a great article on the dangers of recurring background tasks in ASP.NET
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/


Hanselman options:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx