# How to create an event that fires at certain time

Tags: c#, events, windows-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

I have some code that it backups from my data.
I created a windows service and add it to my services in windows.
Now I want to call this service at for example 12 pm.
At a result I want to create an "event" that fires in 12 pm.
How to I create this event?
Thanks.

Comment: u can create scheduled tasks. pretty easy to configure.

Comment: I want to use an event to run my backup