# Windows service scheduling to run daily once a day at 6:00 AM

Tags: c#, windows-services

I had created a windows service and i want that the service will Schedule to run daily at 6:00 Am.
Below is the code which i had written:-

```
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ExtractDataFromSharePoint();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Displays and Logs Message
        _loggerDetails.LogMessage = ex.ToString();
        _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Error, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
    }
}
```

In the above code you can see that in `OnStart` Method of service i am calling a Function `ExtractDataFromSharePoint()`. How i will schedule this to run  daily morning at 6:00 AM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I schedule a C# Windows Service to perform a task daily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503564/how-might-i-schedule-a-c-sharp-windows-service-to-perform-a-task-daily)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here, you have 2 ways to execute your application to run at 6 AM daily.

1) Create a console application and through windows scheduler execute on 6 AM.

2) Create a timer (System.Timers.Timer) in your windows service which executes on every defined interval and in your function, you have to check if the system time = 6 AM then execute your code

```
ServiceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
ServiceTimer.Enabled = true;
ServiceTimer.Interval = 60000 * Interval;
ServiceTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(your function);
```

Note: In your function you have to write the code to execute your method on 6 AM only not every time

Comment: This might not get executed every day at 6:00 as if we set an interval might not have Hrs coinciding with 06 Hrs.

Comment: Hi Jinith,
In that case, you have write logic in you function like

If( System.DateTime.Now() >= 6 AND LastExecutionDateTime.Date == Today.Date)
{
LastExecutionDateTime = System.DateTime.Now();

.

}

Comment: What do you think of using it this way?   ServiceTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;

Answer (score 10):

You don't need a service for this.  Just create a regular console app, then use the Windows scheduler to run your program at 6am.  A service is when you need your program to run all the time.

Answer (score 10):

Here is code that will run within a service every day at 6AM.

include:

```
using System.Threading;
```

also ensure you declare your timer within the class:

```
private System.Threading.Timer _timer = null;
```

The StartTimer function below takes in a start time and an interval period and is currently set to start at 6AM and run every 24 hours.  You could easily change it to start at a different time and interval if needed.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Pass in the time you want to start and the interval
        StartTimer(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0), new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));

    }
    protected void StartTimer(TimeSpan scheduledRunTime, TimeSpan timeBetweenEachRun) {
        // Initialize timer
        double current = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
        double scheduledTime = scheduledRunTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        double intervalPeriod = timeBetweenEachRun.TotalMilliseconds;
        // calculates the first execution of the method, either its today at the scheduled time or tomorrow (if scheduled time has already occurred today)
        double firstExecution = current > scheduledTime ? intervalPeriod - (current - scheduledTime) : scheduledTime - current;

        // create callback - this is the method that is called on every interval
        TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(RunXMLService);

        // create timer
        _timer = new Timer(callback, null, Convert.ToInt32(firstExecution), Convert.ToInt32(intervalPeriod));

    }
    public void RunXMLService(object state) {
        // Code that runs every interval period
    }
```

Comment: Please correct this from

double firstExecution = current > scheduledTime ? intervalPeriod + (current - scheduledTime) : scheduledTime - current;

to

double firstExecution = current > scheduledTime ? intervalPeriod - (current - scheduledTime) : scheduledTime - current;

This will make correct time to run on next interval

Comment: @cmartin as mentioned in the earlier comment change intervalPeriod + (current - scheduledTime) to intervalPeriod - (current - scheduledTime) otherwise it will delay the start time

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @Rachit for your answer and now I am able to fulfill my requirements.

```
static  System.Timers.Timer _timer;
static string _ScheduledRunningTime ="6:00 AM";
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;//Every one minute
        _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Displays and Logs Message
        _loggerDetails.LogMessage = ex.ToString();
        _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Error, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);
     }
 }

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Displays and Logs Message
    _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "timer_Elapsed method at :"+DateTime.Now ;
    _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

    string _CurrentTime=String.Format("{0:t}", DateTime.Now);
    if (_CurrentTime == _ScheduledRunningTime)
    {
        ExtractDataFromSharePoint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a service is really required, look at Quartz.NET to do the scheduling for you

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that makes a call to DB and set the scheduler time based on the results :

Also, you can call a number of API calls which sends regular SMS/emails here itself.

```
public void ScheduleService()
    {
        try
        {
            dsData = new DataSet();
            _timeSchedular = new Timer(new TimerCallback(SchedularCallBack));
            dsData = objDataManipulation.GetInitialSMSConfig();
            if (dsData.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {                    
                DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.MinValue;
                scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(dsData.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUTOSMSTIME"].ToString());
                if (string.Format("{0:dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm}", DateTime.Now) == string.Format("{0:dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm}", scheduledTime))
                {
                    objDataManipulation.WriteToFile("Service Schedule Time Detected");
                    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dsData.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRow++)
                    {
                            if (dsData.Tables.Count > 1)
                            {
                                if (dsData.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    sendData(dsData);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                objDataManipulation.WriteToFile("No SMS Content Data !");
                            }                        }
                }
                if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                {
                    scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1);
                }                   
                TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                string schedule = string.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds(s)", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);

                objDataManipulation.WriteToFile("TexRetail Service scheduled to run after: " + schedule + " {0}");
                int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
                //Change the Timer's Due Time.
                _timeSchedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                              
            objDataManipulation.WriteToFile("Service Error {0}" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + ex.Source);
            using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(ServiceName))
            {
                serviceController.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually HERE I AM GETTING TIME INTERVAL FROM app.config file

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {            
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        this._dbServiceInterval = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceInterval"].ToString());
        timer.Interval = (double)this._dbServiceInterval;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.timerDispatcher_Elapsed);
    }
```