# c# send uploaded file through email daily using asp.net web application

Tags: c#

I just want to know, how to make a web-application which takes input of Excel files from user and send an email daily if that excel file has any new data available.

Should I use web service (with installation of that service in local computer) ? and yes then how to add Upload User-Interface. or Should I use only a web application and Should I add web-service in that application ?

Pls give way to come out of this problem.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the nature of the application you're building:

1. If you want the user to access this over internet, create it as an ASP.NET application (UI) and a Windows Service / Windows Task Scheduler on the Server to send out scheduled emails.
2. If you want the user to run the application from his/her local machine/server, create a windows forms application (UI) and a Windows Service / Windows Task Scheduler on the local machine to send out scheduled emails.

Answer (score 0):

No need of installations to the user computer. You need a simple Web Application and a web server, of course. There are many tutorials about getting started with web applications here are some links:

1. [ASP.NET WebForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243156(v=vs.110).aspx) - obsolete, yet powerful web app paradigm. 
   However, I do recommend the next option, especially if you don't have any previous experience with desktop applications.
2. [ASP.NET MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/808610/First-MVC-Application-for-Beginners) - this is the modern way of building web applications.

Once you made your mind about what technology to use, you gonna need so called [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) server; usually the ISP provides one for you and you gonna need to add a configuration to the web.config, such as:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="*SMTP server IP address*" port="25" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

You can take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0) for details on how to accomplish this in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to it as background job on a Asp.Net WebApp you should look into:

---

[Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

Create a job to send e-mail

```
public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ...Do your stuff;
    }
}
```

Then configure your job to execute daily

```
// define the job and tie it to our SendMailJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SendMailJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 24 hours
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInHours(24)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();
```

---

[HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => YourSendMailMethod("email@email.com"),
    Cron.Daily);
```

---

[IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) (only in Asp.Net Core)

```
public class SendMailHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<SendMailHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public SendMailHostedService(ILogger<SendMailHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        //...Your stuff here

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", executionCount);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your startup.cs class. add this at configure method.

```
services.AddHostedService<SendMailHostedService>();
```

---

If do not need to host it as a backgroud job on your WebApp, then you can create a Windows Service that runs every day on the time you need.

See this question: [Windows service scheduling to run daily once a day at 6:00 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926141/windows-service-scheduling-to-run-daily-once-a-day-at-600-am)