# Send daily notification mail from asp.net mvc web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, quartz.net

I've developed a C# web app MVC that gets some information from another site (Trello) through API calls, and allows the user to do some actions like printing an .xls file with all card details. Now, I want to implement a functionality that sends every day at a specific time in background a mail to my Gmail account with that Excel as an attachment. I want to implement that functionality in an external project but in the same solution, but I don't know how to do that, I heard about quartz.net but I didn't understand how it works and I don't know if that's the right solution. Can anyone help me and give me some tips?

p.s. I can't host the app

EDIT - New question

---

When I try to implement my background job with Quartz.Net I got this error that my class `SendMailJob` doesn't implement an interface member IJob.Execute.

What i have to do?

This is my jobs class:

```
public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    public void SendEmail(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

        Msg.From = new MailAddress("mymail@mail.com", "Me");

        Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("receivermail@mail.com", "ABC"));

        Msg.Subject = "Inviare Mail con C#";

        Msg.Body = "Mail Sended successfuly";
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);

        Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential Credential = new
        NetworkCredential("mymail@mail.com", "password");
        Smtp.Credentials = Credential;

        Smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        Smtp.Send(Msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think something like this would be handled well by a windows service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Comment: If you want to run a service in a separate thread on the same application, then Hangfire would also be the right choice!

Comment: @codeninja.sj You mean [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). But it would be better off hosted in a Windows service or similar, not in a web application.

Comment: If you've already written the code to do what you want, then put it into a console app, make sure it still works as expect on that platform and then run it as a scheduled task.  Web applications are not right for this type of requirement.  They're only really made to respond to requests.  Look at either a scheduled task or a windows service.

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't host the app". Do you want it to be a background job on your webapp or to use windows service in a local machine?

Comment: i didn't write the code that i want to do because i've never worked with emails in my programming experience, I'm also looking for help on how to send a simple email because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @LimiDerjaj. To send e-mail with C# take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp and sendgrid.com

Comment: @LimiDerjaj Sending an email is about 5 lines of code. It's simple. The important part is figuring out *where* the logic should live.

Comment: i wanted to figure this funtionality in an external project in the same solution, what do you think? it id possible?

Comment: @mason where i can find this 5 lines of code to send the email? i got a lot of answers here and they're all different..

Comment: They're all different because they're showing you different ways of doing it. I'm not just going to give you 5 lines of code to send an email - you can find that in plenty of places on the Internet. You could start with looking at Microsoft's documentation for the SmtpClient class.

Comment: [Please don't edit new questions into old ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627). If you have a new question, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a windows service or create a console application and schedule it in windows scheduler.I have implemented the Send-mail service using Windows services.

Comment: i've nevere used them, i don't have a lot of experience on programming, there are some tutorials or documents that can help me with this?

Comment: For creating windows service you can check this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/  .You can Insert the data you want to mail in database tables and then create windows service looping through the data you want to send .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to it as background job on a Asp.Net WebApp you should look into:

---

[Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

Create a job to send e-mail

```
public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        ...Do your stuff;
    }
}
```

Then configure your job to execute daily

```
// define the job and tie it to our SendMailJob class
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SendMailJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 24 hours
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
        .WithIntervalInHours(24)
        .RepeatForever())
    .Build();
```

---

[HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => YourSendMailMethod("email@email.com"),
    Cron.Daily);
```

---

[IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

```
public class SendMailHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<SendMailHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;

    public SendMailHostedService(ILogger<SendMailHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hosted Service running.");

        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        //...Your stuff here

        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", executionCount);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your startup.cs class. add this at configure method.

```
services.AddHostedService<SendMailHostedService>();
```

---

If do not need to host it as a backgroud job on your WebApp, then you can create a Windows Service that runs every day on the time you need.

See this question: [Windows service scheduling to run daily once a day at 6:00 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23926141/windows-service-scheduling-to-run-daily-once-a-day-at-600-am)

---

To send E-mails with C# you can take a look a `SmptClient` class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?view=netframework-4.8

Or use a service, like SendGrid, that can do it for you.

EDIT:

---

About your second question:

When you implements an interface your class should have all methods defined on that interface.

This methods needs to be public, return the same type, has the same name and receive the same parameters that was declared on the interface you implement.

In your specific case, you just miss the method name. Just change it do Execute like below.

EDIT: As you are using Quartz.net 3, the `IJbo` interface returns a Task and not void. So I changed the class `SendMailJob` to return a task of your existing method.

```
public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SendEmail());
    }

    public void SendMail()
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

        Msg.From = new MailAddress("mymail@mail.com", "Me");

        Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("receivermail@mail.com", "ABC"));

        Msg.Subject = "Inviare Mail con C#";

        Msg.Body = "Mail Sended successfuly";
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);

        Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential Credential = new
        NetworkCredential("mymail@mail.com", "password");
        Smtp.Credentials = Credential;

        Smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        Smtp.Send(Msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi i wrote the code to send the email and it works (i've tried to send the email when i click a button in the index view, just for try if the code, and it was correct) now i wanted to do it as a daily background job with Quartz.net like you reccomended me. I've created a new class SendEmailJob : IJob but it tells me that it doesn't implement an interface member IJob.Execute, what i have to do?

Comment: I do not reccomended Quartz. I just give you options. Quartz.net is one of this options.

Comment: @Limi Please update your question with the code of your SendEmailJob class

Comment: i've updated my question, the problem is here: public class SendMailJob : IJob  (i don't know why the first part of the code is not shown as a code)

Comment: Please. Please. Please. Please. Please. Please. Please. Do not change all context of your question after you got answers. It will be really hard for others users understand the problem and the solution. Remember that StackOverflow only is a good site today because it is very organized. Let's keep it organized. I edited your question for you, but it will only appear for you after moderator's review.

Comment: For now. Just change the name of the SendEmail method to Execute and then study about how interfaces works.

Comment: I edited my answer with some information about interfaces and how to fix your code. Happy I could help.

Comment: To configure my job to execute daily i just need the two paragraphs that you answered to me (Create a job, and configure it to execute daily) ? I'm searching for a tutorial on how to use quartz properly  because i didn't understand how it works...                                                                                    and in the : IJob it still give me an error: Cannot implement the IJob.Execute because it doesn't have the matching return type of 'Task

Comment: @Limi. You start the question asking how to do a background job in asp.net. Now we are talking about specifics of Quartz.Net. Please could you create a new question about this new doubts?

Comment: i can't create the question, i have to wait 2 days haha i'm sorry for the mistakes i made, i thought that my question was inherent with quartz.net specific because it is the solution for my question

Comment: Try this: public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)

Comment: it need the await? or i don't need to write it?

Comment: Try remove the async from method. It will not ask for the await. I forgot your method is not async.

Comment: it tells me not all code paths return a value, maybe i have to put the part of code to configure my job to execute daily?

Comment: @LimiDerjaj I realize that you are using Quartz.net 3. That has some little chages from my previous example. So I update it with tha changes needed.

Comment: @LimiDerjaj did it help you? Could you implement your solution?

Comment: hi, i  have just tried it and it works, thank you very much

Comment: Good. As it helped you can you mark it as correct, or upvote? It will help other users with the same problem on the future too.

Comment: where can i mark it as corrected?

Comment: On the left side of the answer. Bellow the down vote button. It look like a V

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) which lets you schedule background jobs and backs them with persistent storage.

You can then easily schedule a recurring job like:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => SendEmail("user@domain"),
    Cron.Daily);
```

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/index.html - the first tutorial is about sending email

Comment: i've never worked with emails in programming and i've never used hangfire, can you please help me on how it works? there aren't tutorials online?

Comment: @LimiDerjaj https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/tutorials/index.html